Tengo problemas con datatables. Es en la pagination y en la llamada de datos para la primera página
Tengo esta configuración en JS la cual consiste en llamar datos para un tabla. Cada tab activa una función
$(document).ready(function(){$('#myTab button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', async function (e) {
    // limpiarfunciones();

    var target = $(e.target).attr("data-bs-target");     
    
    if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablaact_fechasvcon')){            
        $('#tablaact_fechasvcon tbody').empty();
    }

    if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablainact_fechasvcon')){            
        $('#tablainact_fechasvcon tbody').empty();
    }

    if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablacot_fechasvcon')){            
        $('#tablacot_fechasvcon tbody').empty();
    }

    if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon')){            
        $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon tbody').empty();
    }

    if (target === '#tabact_fechasvcon') {
        tabact_fechasvcon();
        $('#comboact_fechasvcon').val('Productos');
        $('#colact_fechasvcon').text('Productos');
        $('[name="dt_buscar_tablaact"]').val('');
    } else if (target === '#tabinact_fechasvcon') {
        tabinact_fechasvcon();
        $('#comboinact_fechasvcon').val('Productos');
        $('#colinact_fechasvcon').text('Productos');
        $('[name="dt_buscar_tablainact"]').val('');
    } else if (target === '#tabcot_fechasvcon') { 
        tabcot_fechasvcon();  
        $('#combocot_fechasvcon').val('Pendientes');
        $('#colcot_fechasvcon').text('Pendientes');
        $('[name="dt_buscar_tablacot"]').val('');
    } else 
    if (target === '#tabclientes_fechasvcon'){
        tabclientes_fechasvcon();
        $('#comboclientes_fechasvcon').val('Disponibles');
        $('[name="dt_buscar_tablaclientes"]').val('');
    }
}); }

Pero solo en una tengo un problema que no he podido resolver en tres semanas. Cada función de cada pestaña contiene la misma configuración de la datatable, sin embargo por alguna razón no me funciona bien la función siguiente...
    function tabclientes_fechasvcon()
{
    $('#comboclientes_fechasvcon').change(function(){
        var datocombo = $(this).val();
        
        if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon')){
            $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
        }

        $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon tbody').empty();

        if(datocombo === 'Disponibles'){
            clientesdisp_fechasvcon();
        } else if(datocombo === 'No Disponibles'){
            clientesnodisp_fechasvcon();
        }
    });

    clientesdisp_fechasvcon();

    function clientesdisp_fechasvcon(fechauno, fechados)
    {
        if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablaact_fechasvcon')){
            $('#tablaact_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
        }
        if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablainact_fechasvcon')){
            $('#tablainact_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
        }
        if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablacot_fechasvcon')){
            $('#tablacot_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
        }
        if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon')){
            $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
        }
    
        $('[name="tablaclientes_fechasvcon_length"]').val('10');
        $('#pagination_act_fechasvcon').empty();
        $('#pagination_inact_fechasvcon').empty();        
        $('#pagination_cot_fechasvcon').empty();
        $('#pagination_clientes_fechasvcon').empty();
        $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon tbody').empty();        
    
        var tablaclientesdisp_fechasvcon = $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon').DataTable({
            language:{
                'zeroRecords': 'No se encontraron coincidencias',
                'emptyTable': 'No hay datos disponibles'
            },
            'autoWidth': false,
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'ordering': false,        
            'ajax':{
                'url': 'cconsulta_fechas/tablaclientesdisp_fechasvcon',
                'type': 'POST',
                'dataType': 'JSON',
                'data': {
                    'fechauno': fechauno,
                    'fechados': fechados
                },            
                'error': function(xhr, error, code){
                    alert('Error al hacer la petición');
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    console.error('XHR:', xhr);
                    console.error('Code:', code);
    
                    if(xhr.responseText){
                        console.error('Respuesta del error:', xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }
            },
            'columns': [
                {'data': 'id', 'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    $(td).addClass('text-center');
                }},
                {'data': 'nombre', 'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    $(td).addClass('text-center');
                }},
                {'data': 'disponible_vtotal', 'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    var disponible_vtotal = cellData.trim();
                    $(td).addClass('text-center').html('<span id="celda_disponible_vtotal" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px">'+cellData+'</span>');
    
                    if(disponible_vtotal === 'DISPONIBLE'){
                        $(td).find('span').addClass('badge badge-primary');
                    } 
                }},
                {'data': 'fecha_vtotal', 'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    $(td).addClass('text-center');
                }},
                {'data': null,
                    'orderable': false,
                    'searchable': false,
                    'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col)
                    {
                        var id = rowData.id;
                        var disponibles_ver = `<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success fa-regular fa-eye" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#" onclick="ver_vconfechas(${id})"></button>`;
                        $(td).addClass('text-center').html(disponibles_ver);
                    }
                }
            ],
            'dom': 'rt<"bottom"p>',
            'initComplete': function(){
                var pagination = $('.pagination');
                pagination.attr('id', 'pagination_clientesfechasvcon');
                $('#pagination_clientes_fechasvcon').append(pagination);
            },
            'drawCallback': function(settings){
                var api = this.api();
                var rows = api.rows({page: 'current'}).data().length;
    
                console.log('Pruebas:', rows);
                var buscador_disp = $('[name="dt_buscar_tablaclientes"]').val().length;
    
                if(rows === 0 && buscador_disp > 5){
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: "Petición no Concedida",
                        text: "No se encontraron datos",
                        icon: "warning",
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    });
    
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
                        $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon tbody').empty();
                        $('[name="dt_buscar_tablaclientes"]').val('');
                        fechauno = '';
                        fechados = '';
                        clientesdisp_fechasvcon(fechauno, fechados);
                    }, 2000);
                }
    
                var pagination = $('.pagination');
                pagination.attr('id', 'pagination_clientesfechasvcon');
                $('#pagination_clientes_fechasvcon').html('');
            }
        });
    
        $('[name="dt_buscar_tablaclientes"]').on('keyup', function(){
            tablaclientesdisp_fechasvcon.search(this.value).draw();
        });    
    
        $('[name="tablaclientes_fechasvcon_length"]').on('change', function(){
            tablaclientesdisp_fechasvcon.page.len(this.value).draw();
        });    
    
        tablaclientesdisp_fechasvcon.on('draw', function(){
            var pagination = $('.pagination');
            pagination.attr('id', 'pagination_clientesfechasvcon');
            $('#pagination_clientes_fechasvcon').append(pagination);
        });
    }
    
    function clientesnodisp_fechasvcon(fechauno, fechados)
    {
        if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablaact_fechasvcon')){
            $('#tablaact_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
        }
        if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablainact_fechasvcon')){
            $('#tablainact_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
        }
        if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablacot_fechasvcon')){
            $('#tablacot_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
        }
        if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon')){
            $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
        }
    
        $('[name="tablaclientes_fechasvcon_length"]').val('10');
        $('#pagination_act_fechasvcon').empty();
        $('#pagination_inact_fechasvcon').empty();        
        $('#pagination_cot_fechasvcon').empty();
        $('#pagination_clientes_fechasvcon').empty();
        $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon tbody').empty();
    
        var tablaclientesnodisp_fechasvcon = $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon').DataTable({
            language:{
                'zeroRecords': 'No se encontraron coincidencias',
                'emptyTable': 'No hay datos disponibles'
            },
            'autoWidth': false,
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'ordering': false,
            'ajax':{
                'url': 'cconsulta_fechas/tablaclientesnodisp_fechasvcon',
                'type': 'POST',
                'dataType': 'JSON',
                'data':{
                    'fechauno': fechauno,
                    'fechados': fechados
                },
                'error': function(xhr, error, code){
                    alert('Error al hacer la petición');
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    console.error('XHR:', xhr);
                    console.error('Code:', code);
    
                    if(xhr.responseText){
                        console.error('Respuesta del error:', xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }
            },
            'columns':[
                {'data': 'id', 'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    $(td).addClass('text-center');
                }},
                {'data': 'nombre', 'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    $(td).addClass('text-center');
                }},
                {'data': 'disponible_vtotal', 'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    var disponible_vtotal = cellData.trim();
                    $(td).addClass('text-center').html('<span id="celda_disponible_vtotal" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px">'+cellData+'</span>');
    
                    if(disponible_vtotal === 'DISPONIBLE'){
                        $(td).find('span').addClass('badge badge-primary');
                    } else if(disponible_vtotal === 'NO DISPONIBLE'){
                        $(td).find('span').addClass('badge badge-dark');
                    }
                }},
                {'data': 'fecha_vtotal', 'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    $(td).addClass('text-center');
                }},
                {'data': null,
                    'orderable': false,
                    'searchable': false,
                    'createdCell': function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col)
                    {
                        var id = rowData.id;
                        var disponible_ver = `<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success fa-regular fa-eye" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#" onclick="ver_vconfechas(${id})"></button>`;
                        $(td).addClass('text-center').html(disponible_ver);
                    }
                }
            ],
            'dom': 'rt<"bottom"p>',
            'initComplete': function(){
                var pagination = $('.pagination');
                pagination.attr('id', 'pagination_clientesfechasvcon');
                $('#pagination_clientes_fechasvcon').append(pagination);
            },
            'drawCallback': function(settings){
                var api = this.api();
                var rows = api.rows({page: 'current'}).data().length;
                var buscador_nodisp = $('[name="dt_buscar_tablaclientes"]').val().length;
    
                if(rows === 0 && buscador_nodisp > 5){
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: "Petición no Concedida",
                        text: "No se encontraron datos",
                        icon: "warning",
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        timer: 2000
                    });
                    
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon').DataTable().destroy();
                        $('#tablaclientes_fechasvcon tbody').empty();
                        $('[name="dt_buscar_tablaclientes"]').val('');
                        fechauno = '';
                        fechados = '';
                        clientesnodisp_fechasvcon(fechauno, fechados);
                    }, 2000);
                }
    
                var pagination = $('.pagination');
                pagination.attr('id', 'pagination_clientesfechasvcon');
                $('#pagination_clientes_fechasvcon').html('');
            }
        });
    
        $('[name="dt_buscar_tablaclientes"]').on('keyup', function(){
            tablaclientesnodisp_fechasvcon.search(this.value).draw();
        });
    
        $('[name="tablaclientes_fechasvcon_length"]').on('change', function(){
            tablaclientesnodisp_fechasvcon.page.len(this.value).draw();
        });
    
        tablaclientesnodisp_fechasvcon.on('draw', function(){
            var pagination = $('.pagination');
            pagination.attr('id', 'pagination_clientesfechasvcon');
            $('#pagination_clientes_fechasvcon').append(pagination);
        });
    }
}

La función esta dentro de la función. Me refiero a la función clientesdisp_fechasvcon. Esta función no me rellena la primer página de la paginación, además de que no me muestra de 10 en 10, de 20 en 20 (Según lo que se pida mostrar por página), en la paginación. Al contrario, solo me va sumando la lista de arriba hacia abajo.
Y debería mostrar 10 en vez del 145 porque así lo pido con la cantidad de información.
Espero puedan ayudarme.
